# Replace matrix/dataframe values found in column i with i-th element of vector

Tags: r, matrix, replace, dataframe

Supose you have a 3 by 3 matrix `m` with one or more zeros and you want to replace each zero by a given number.

The replacement must follow this rule:

If a zero is found on first column of `m`, then it should be replaced with the first element of vector `v`, if a zero is found on second column of `m`, then it should be replaced with the second element of vector `v`, and the same for the third column/vector element.

The matrix and the vector are:

```
m <- matrix(c(0,2,3,4,0,6,0,8,0), 3, 3, byrow = TRUE)
v <- c(1,5,9)
```

Of course, the `length` of `v` must match the number of columns in `m`. So the matrix is like this:

```
0 2 3
4 0 6
0 8 0
```

I want that whenever R finds a zero in the first column of `m` it replaces it by the first element of vector `v`, and so on, so that the final result would be:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
1 8 9
```

I have done a lot of research and havent found a solution for this problem. Can someone please help?

Comment: `m[m==0] <- v[1]` gives the desired result

Comment: In your desired result, contrary to your problem description, you always replace zeros with `v[1]`.

Comment: Your description made is sound as though that the result should be `matrix( c(1,4,1,2,5,8,3,6,9), 3)`

Comment: Yes, in my description i've failled to reproduce correctly the final result. I will edit the question in order to correct this.

Comment: @42-: Thanks for your edit. I've noticed that you added the `byrow = TRUE`.

Comment: Edited the title so it can better summarize the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought your proposed solution is wrong and here is a solution to thep problem described in your text. When `which` is called with `.arr.ind=TRUE` it returns a two column matrix which can be used for matrix or dataframe indexing as i,i reference. In this case you can also use its second column as an index to the `v`-object.

```
> m[ which(m==0, arr.ind=TRUE) ] <- v[ which(m==0, arr.ind=TRUE)[,2] ]
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    1    8    9
```

Comment: Thanks 42-. Your answer tells me I should learn more about the `which` command and the `arr.ind` parameter. Thank you very much

Comment: Or `m[m==0] <- v[col(m)[m==0]]` as a variation

Comment: That looks pretty slick. Will need to see what other potential that has. Feel free to post an alternate answer. I'd certainly upvote it.

Answer (score 4):

```
m + t((t(m) == 0) * v)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    3
# [2,]    4    5    6
# [3,]    1    8    9
```

or

```
m + sweep(m == 0, 2, v, `*`)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    3
# [2,]    4    5    6
# [3,]    1    8    9
```

Comment: OP wants it column-wise, so I think it should be: `m + t((t(m) == 0) * v)`

Comment: Thanks Julius. Your answer uses matrix multiplication and I like it very much this way of solving the problem.

Comment: It did seem like a sweep of sorts. I'm still staring at it wonder how it actually works.